# didReceiveRemoteNotification not called in Background Mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, apple-push-notifications

I am working on push notifications and the data I receive is in JSON format. How can I parse the JSON data, which is shown in the Notification Center below:

[image: I only need the description]

Comment: To parse JSON, check out [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSJSONSerialization).

Comment: @krishna - r u checked this

Answer (score 7):

if your app in background/foreground mode call this method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler
```

if you used the above method you will face the following error in console

> application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:], but you still need to add "remote-notification" to the list of your supported UIBackgroundModes in your Info.plist.

*To Resolve this issue*

follow the image of steps

[image]

if your app in foreground mode call this method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo
```

**choice no-2**

```
   - (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
  UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    // user tapped notification while app was in background
if (state == UIApplicationStateInactive || state == UIApplicationStateBackground) {
     // go to screen relevant to Notification content
} else {
     // App is in UIApplicationStateActive (running in foreground)
     // perhaps show an UIAlertView
}
}
```

**Swift**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
var state: UIApplicationState = application.applicationState()
// user tapped notification while app was in background
if state == .Inactive || state == .Background {
    // go to screen relevant to Notification content
}
else {
    // App is in UIApplicationStateActive (running in foreground)
    // perhaps show an UIAlertView
}
}
```

Comment: check the updated answer brother, if u need assistance I hope with you, i am waiting for your reply ,

Comment: Thanks @Anbu.Karthik by changing the format of payload...worked for me.

Comment: if my answer is fine give the upvote, it is useful for future

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik not working, please help to my question https://stackoverflow.com/q/63598194/8822337

Answer (score 1):

If didReceiveRemoteNotification method is not called in background mode,please follow the below steps

First ON the Push Notification and Tick the check box of Remote Notifications of Background Mode in Capabilities of Target

Then

```
-(void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo  fetchCompletionHandler:(void  
(^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler  
{  

   if( [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive )  
   {  
      NSLog( @"INACTIVE" );  
   } 
   else if( [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground )  
   {  
      NSLog( @"BACKGROUND" );  
   }  
   else  
   {  
      NSLog( @"FOREGROUND" ); 
   }  

   return YES;
}
```

Comment: the questioner asked the notification center is not called in background mode , please update your answer or else check my answer

Comment: Why do you make `return`, this method has `void` return value?