# didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is not called up in ios8

Tags: ios, iphone

I know this question already asked previously and also have some solution for it,i tried all the solution available ,but nothing is working for me. Code is working perfectly on my side but when i submit the App store they reject it (till now i got 3 rejections from App store).

I try the the code from the following link:-

[why didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086599/why-didregisterforremotenotificationswithdevicetoken-is-not-called)

[Get Device Token in iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24426090/get-device-token-in-ios-8)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html

I also check provisional profile and certificates they all are fine.

Anyone please help

Comment: So what was their response ? Why did they reject it ?

Comment: see this link may be helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31967093/didreceiveremotenotification-not-called-in-background-mode/31969405#31969405

Comment: what you have implemented ? can you show your code here? and are you sure the reason given by Apple for App rejection is push notification? Can you paste reason here?

Answer (score 0):

Push notification registration process has been changed in iOS 8, Make sure you have added this

```
 if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];

}
```

Comment: Are you able to receive notification in iOS 7 and iOS 8 both?

Answer (score 0):

I have used this way. I didn't get any issue from app store.

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
    //register to receive notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
#endif
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)notification completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
{
    NSLog(@"Received push notification: %@, identifier: %@", notification, identifier); // iOS 8 s
    completionHandler();
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken
{
    NSString *newToken = [devToken description];
    newToken = [newToken stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    newToken = [newToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

    NSLog(@"NotificationToken: %@",newToken);

}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error while registering for notifications: %@", error);
}
```