# IOS push notifications not received

Tags: php, python, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I configured my app:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        let pushSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(
                forTypes:[.Alert, .Badge, .Sound],
                categories: nil)
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(pushSettings)
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
        return true
    }

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
        print("My token is: \(deviceToken)");
    }

    // Failed to register for Push
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
        print("Failed to get token; error: %@", error) //Log an error for debugging purposes, user doesn't need to know
    }
```

Copy my device token, to my python script:

```
import time
from apns import APNs, Frame, Payload

apns = APNs(use_sandbox=True, cert_file='NodesDownCert.pem', key_file='NodesDownKey.pem')

# Send a notification
token_hex = 'xxx'
payload = Payload(alert="Hello World!", sound="default")
apns.gateway_server.send_notification(token_hex, payload)
```

I ran script, it didn't return errors, but i haven't received notifications at my Ipad. I  tried php script from this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1), script returns **"Message successfully delivered"**, but i'm still not receive any message. [Php code here](http://pastebin.com/LkEYaSud).

Any ideas how to debug or what is wrong ?

Comment: see this link may be helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31967093/didreceiveremotenotification-not-called-in-background-mode/31969405#31969405

Comment: I have enabled "Remote notifications" at capabilities tab, but still not work..

Comment: i even use this app https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apn-tester-free/id626590577?mt=12

Comment: but it doesn't work :(

Comment: initally are you get the permission alert on your app

Comment: yes, http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12/basic-app-2-allow-notifications   like this

Comment: else check your device_token  or a .pem file embedded with your php code

Comment: it will occur in many scenario how do we say some excat answer